# Custom Google Sheets function

Tags: function, google-apps-script, arguments, google-sheets, date-range

I'm trying to write a custom function that looks a like this:

```
function myFunction(arg1, arg2){
   //some calculations on the range described by these two arguments
   return value of the calculation
}
```

`arg1` is a cell from a spreadsheet formatted as `A1`

`arg2` is a second cell reference `A2`

I need these two arguments to point to a range on another worksheet within the same spreadsheet. Somewhat like this: `range A1:A2 on Sheet2`

I can get the spreadsheet Sheet2 and get the range when I use the code `"A1:A2"` as an argument for `getRange()`.

Things go bad when I do this:

```
var range = arg1 & ":" & arg2;
var sheetRange = sheet2.getRange(range);
```

I'm sure there is a syntax problem here that makes it impossible for the function to interpret `range` as a range.

And I am completely stumped... Any help, direction to a good syntax reference site or some good tutorials are also appreciated. As is the answer to my problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

Even after you correct your api and syntax errors it will still fail because custom functions must be deterministic. Since you pass the range name and not its value, your function will return a previous calculation if you pass the same range again but the range values changed.
Tldr either pass the values not the range names or dont use custom functions for this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Zig. I'm very new to scripting as a whole. Does your answer mean that it is impossible to use two string arguments and format them in such a way that getRange() accepts them as a range?

Comment: The basic thing I would like to do is create something like a custum SUM function. I would pass a range like SUM(A1:A2) but then how would I go by making this work? Hope this helps clarify what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Its possible to build the range string and get its data but like i said it wont work correctly because custom functions are deterministic.

Comment: okay, thanks for the answer. I'll look at soe other ways to handle this. regards.

Answer (score 0):

When you select a range of values and pass it to a function they'll show up in your code as an array, for more information on arrays view this page: http://javascript.info/tutorial/array

Comment: Can you whip up a sample google spreadsheet to help this guy out?

Answer (score 0):

I made an example for you. Check it here: [example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lP6ePhRndLhA7QjO7VuYoRj5nQuMQTBXazcC9vHzQsY/edit?usp=sharing)

```
/**
 * custom function
 * 
 * @customfunction
 */
function myFunc(input){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');

if (input.map) {            // Test whether input is an array.
    return input.map(myFunc); // Recurse over array if so.
  } else {
    return sheet.getRange(1, input).getValue();
  }
}
```

It takes as input the range of values from sheet1, but populates the target cells with entries from sheet 2, using the inputs as column numbers for the 1st row in *Sheet2*. Hope this helps.